# azure logic apps can't reference table column in sql getrows

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

trying to create a simple logic app that will run once a week, retrieve rows in a sql table using get rows and then use the mobilephone column from the sql data to send a text message using the twilio connector.

setup the recurrence fine, chose sql get rows and pointed it at the table, no problem

When I add the send text message using twilio I am unable to look at the columns in the data to select the mobile phone number.?.  Not sure what I am missing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

talked with Microsoft support who was really helpful!  Said I can't reference back in designer have to do it in the code.  Here is the JSON code:

"definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Send_Text_Message_(SMS)_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "body": {
                                **"body": "@items('For_each')?['Message']"**,
                                "from": "+15082139682",
                                **"to": "@items('For_each')?['MobilePhone']"**
                            },
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['twilio']['connectionId']"
                                }